# Grab an id that is not in relationship to another id in sql statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these two table, sorry for not being able to embed it due to lack of reputation. Currently, I am trying to grab the id of the person who is not friend with the userId '1'.

For instance, in friendlist Table, it shows that user Id '1' is friend with userId '2' and '3'. However, he is not friend with userId '4' and '5'.

So I want to grab the userId of 4 and 5.

I tried to grab friendId and using operator '<>' to grab non-friend Id but it doesn't work.

May I know how to?

[friendlist Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gA90N.png)

[registeredUser Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9a2D.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a statement like this one:

```
SELECT * FROM registeredUser WHERE userId NOT IN (SELECT friendId FROM friendlist WHERE userId = 1) AND userId != 1;
```

This will return all the users that are not friends with the user which has the `userId` 1.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. However, is it possible to not return the user with userId 1 as well?

Comment: @AlvinAng Yes, I've modified the statement to do that.

Answer (score 0):

For you referance:

```
select u.userId from registerUser u, friendlist f 
where u.userId=f.userId and (f.friendId=4 or f.friendId=5);
```